# Evaluating 2 ActiveRecord .where queries with logical operators in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to implement a basic messenger system in a rails app. I was following a guide who proposed the following code in the create method.

```
    if Conversation.between?(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present?
        @conversation = Conversation.between?(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
        @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end
```

The objective is to only create a new conversation when there was none already open for the same two users, otherwise it creates a new one.

I've tried to use this code but it returns an error:

```
undefined method `between?' for nil:NilClass
```

despite @conversations is not nil. The method between? doesn't seem to be available.

I've tried to write a convoluted ActiveRecod query below

```
    @session = Conversation.where('recipient_id = params[:sender_id] and sender_id = params[:recipient_id]') + Conversation.where('recipient_id = params[:recipient_id] and sender_id = params[:sender_id]')
```

but it raises

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "params" does not exist LINE 1: ...ons".* FROM "conversations" WHERE (recipient_id = params[:se... ^ : SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE (recipient_id = params[:sender_id] and sender_id = params[:recipient_id]) LIMIT $1
```

my whole controller below:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @users = User.all
    @profiles = Profile.all
    @conversations = Conversation.all
 end

def create

    @session = Conversation.where('recipient_id = params[:sender_id] and sender_id = params[:recipient_id]') + Conversation.where('recipient_id = params[:recipient_id] and sender_id = params[:sender_id]')

    if @session.present?
      @conversation = @session.first
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
end

private

def conversation_params
    params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
end
end
```

and my Conversation model

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'Profile'
  belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'Profile'
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id

  scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
  where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ? ) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ? )", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end

end
```

Finally my view

```
    <h1>conversations</h1>

<div class=”ui segment”>
    <h3>Mailbox</h3>
    <div class=”ui list”>
        <div class=”item”>
            <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
                <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
                    <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
                    <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
                <% else %>
                    <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
                <% end %>
            <%= link_to recipient.firstname,   conversation_messages_path(conversation)%>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class=”ui segment”>
    <h3>All Users</h3>
    <div class=”ui list”>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <% if user.id != current_user.id %>
        <div class=”item”>
            <%= user.firstname %>
            <%= link_to "Message me!", conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id), method: :post %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was hoping someone can provide a comment on why that particular query syntax raises an error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would check if there is a conversation between two people by using a `merge` query.

I guess you have a class for these `sender` and `receiver` such as `User`?

```
sender = User.find(first_user)
receiver = User.find(second_user)

if ((conversations = sender.conversations.merge(receiver.conversations)).any?)
  @conversation = conversations.first
else
  @conversation = Conversation.create(sender: sender, receiver: receiver)
end
```

Comment: Hi David thanks. Not sure how to implement your suggestion. I'm grabbing the sender and recipient id's from a list of usernames. Those parameters are passed through the url and thus are the one trying to use here. I've pasted  the complete controller and edited my questions and perhaps makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally realised that the syntax "attribute=value and attribute=value"  for the Where query, when combined with an other query raises an error. Not sure why. So I moved to the traditional hash syntax "attribute: value" and it worked.